# Group list by elements of nested list

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, grouping

I have got Car object with parameters like:

```
private String model;
private BigDecimal price;
private Color color;
private BigDecimal milleage;
private List<String> components;
```

I created list of Car objects:

```
var cars = List.of(
    Car.create("FORD", BigDecimal.valueOf(120000), Color.RED, BigDecimal.valueOf(150000),
            List.of("AIR CONDITIONING", "VOICE SERVICE")),
    Car.create("FORD", BigDecimal.valueOf(160000), Color.RED, BigDecimal.valueOf(150000),
            List.of("AIR CONDITIONING", "VOICE SERVICE")),
    Car.create("AUDI", BigDecimal.valueOf(200000), Color.BLACK, BigDecimal.valueOf(195000),
            List.of("NAVIGATION", "AUTOMATIC GEARBOX")),
    Car.create("FIAT", BigDecimal.valueOf(70000), Color.BLUE, BigDecimal.valueOf(85000),
            List.of("AIR CONDITIONING", "MANUAL GEARBOX")));
```

Now I want to create `Map<String, List<Car>>` where the string is element of component list and `List<Car>>` is list of `Car` objects which contain this component.

I tried something like this based on some similar problems but really do not know how to solve this problem:

```
static Map<String, List<Car>> carsThatGotComponent(List<Car> cars) {
    return cars.stream()
               .flatMap(car -> car.getComponents()
                       .stream()
                       .map(component -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(car, component)))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collectors#mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) requires as a second parameter a downstream `Collector`, not a mapping function.

> ```
> public static <T,U,A,R> Collector<T,?,R> mapping(
>     Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper, 
>     Collector<? super U,A,R> downstream)
> ```

You want to use `Collectors.toList()` instead:

```
return cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getComponents()
                       .stream()
                       .map(component -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(car, component)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
            Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

As long as you use [java-10](/questions/tagged/java-10) or later, you can use simplify the whole Stream into one collector using [`Collectors#flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) as of [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9):

```
return cars.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.flatMapping(
             car -> car.getComponents()
                       .stream()
                       .map(component -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(car, component)),
             Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                     Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, 
                             Collectors.toList()))));
```